# Мигает Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

Во время написания программы на python'е в VS 2019 окно постоянно мигает (точнее, только значок и верхняя строчка, само окно переходит из активного состояния в нормальное). Что делать?

Comment: Она не мигает, а подмигивает;)

Comment: Это скорее нервный тик(.

Answer (score -1):

Он может "подмигивать", если, к примеру, у вас есть обновления пакетов или же самого VS CODE-а
Или же, вполне, это какой-то баг , который может быть связан с вашей системой

Comment: Возможно есть какой-то баг, я, к сожалению, не знаю (потому я и спросил, вдруг кто-то уже сталкивался с этим). Но вот обновления я уже проверял и их нет.